# Rxswift observable bind(to:) vs subscribe(onNext:)

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Sorry. I am confused what is binding in Rxswift. As far as I know, `observable` won't produce value unless a observer subscribed on it, e.g `myObservable.subscribe(onNext: {})`. 

But when I read the follow line of code:

```
// in LoginViewModel.swift
init() {
    isValid = Observable.combineLatest(username.asObservable(), password.asObservable()) { (username, password) in
        return !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty
    }
}

// in LoginViewController.swift
viewModel.isValid.bind(to: loginButton.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I am confused here why the `isValid` Observable is able to be observed without calling a `subscribe` method on it?
Why we can just call bind(to:) in `LoginViewController.swift` without calling something like `viewModel.isValid.subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look at the implementation of `bind(to: )`

```
public func bind<O: ObserverType>(to observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
    return self.subscribe(observer)
}
```

Subscribe is called inside.

Regarding your statement

> As far as I know, observable won't produce value unless a observer subscribed on it

This is only true for **cold** observables. Let me quote from [RxSwift docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/HotAndColdObservables.md)

> When does an Observable begin emitting its sequence of items? It depends on the Observable. A “hot” Observable may begin emitting items as soon as it is created, and so any observer who later subscribes to that Observable may start observing the sequence somewhere in the middle. A “cold” Observable, on the other hand, waits until an observer subscribes to it before it begins to emit items, and so such an observer is guaranteed to see the whole sequence from the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

Since I stumbled upon this question trying understand the difference between those two I would like to add that for `bind`:

> In case error occurs in debug mode, `fatalError` will be raised.
>       In case error occurs in release mode, `error` will be logged.

The approach is **different** for `subscribe(onNext:` which allows to **explicitly** handle `onError:` with custom handling (same for `onCompleted` `onDisposed`).

As @chriswillow already answered **both** `bind` and `subscribe(onNext:` **do subscribe** to an observable.